# i'm getting an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, collections

The environment details i'm running my program :

> java version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
> (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-224) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
> 17.0.7+8-LTS-224, mixed mode, sharing)

Program:

```
public class Conversions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Integer> lIn = new ArrayList<>();
        lIn.add(4);
        lIn.add(56);
        lIn.add(423);
        lIn.add(2516);
        lIn.add(924);
        lIn.add(5611);

        //ArrayList to Array
        int[] conArray = lIn.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
        
        
        // Array to ArrayList
        
        int[] arr = {5,8,9,34,63,119};
        List<Integer> convList = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toList();
        System.out.println(convList);    //30   
                                         //31
        Collections.sort(convList);      //32
        Collections.reverse(convList);   //33

    }

}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException    at
> java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:142)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableList.sort(ImmutableCollections.java:261)
> at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:145)   at
> com.example.DependencyInjection.Conversions.main**(Conversions.java:32)

I'm trying to  understand why the compiler is throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` even though i'm using the `Collections.sort()` method correctly . All I'm doing is passing a list but still I'm getting the exception.

Comment: All you're doing is passing an *immutable* list. Why not do the sorts in the stream? Why all the boxing and unboxing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list returned by `.toList()` (a method of `Stream`) is immutable. Sorting it (`.sort()`) sorts 'in place' and this requires mutating the list. You can't do that.

The usual fix is to first copy the immutable list into a mutable one: `convList = new ArrayList<Integer>(convList);`.

However, all of your code is a bit suspect. Why go from `int[]` to `List<Integer>` to `Stream` and back again?

EDIT: Let's just leave 'I want to go from one to another' as written - instead of making a list and then trying to sort the list, instead sort the stream as it 'runs':

```
List<Integer> convList = Arrays.stream(arr)
  .sorted()  // Add this!
  .boxed()
  .toArray();
```

Comment: There’s no such equivalent for the `Collections.reverse(…)` call though. So if the OP wants a descending list, the solution would be `List<Integer> convList = Arrays.stream(arr) .boxed() .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()) .toArray();`

Comment: There is in this case (sort first, reverse after) - reverse the comparator function. I find `Comparator.reverseOrder()` a badly named method - it implies that it simply reverses the elements. But that's not what it does: `reverseOrder()` applies the reverse of natural order. There is no way to write a comparator that reverses a list. This is where we get into a ton of exotic details about how the stream API works :(

Comment: That's what I said; there is no stream operator to just reverse the order, but the OP's specific case of getting descending order is solvable (but requires sorting the boxed values).

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
  List<Integer> convList = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toList();
```

with

```
List<Integer> convList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toList());
```

It will create a new mutable list which will be further sorted by

```
Collections.sort(convList);
```

Without any issues.

Hope this helps